# Loading from external file (DLL with other extension name)

Tags: c++, dynamic, dll, resources, loading

I got a little problem right here on my Application. Let's come to the point,
i wanna load my sounds from an external file, actually called D8_Sounds.src (before D8_Sounds.dll). I am using LoadLibrary() because with GetModuleHandle() this "extension"-switch wouldn't work. Well, it plays the sounds BUT the problem there is the Application asks for a D8_Sounds.dll... Everytime to load the data from D8_Sounds.src it needs the D8_Sounds.dll.

I am using Visual Studio 2013 Professional & added (of course) the Project Solution D8_Sounds to the Application project.

What am i doing wrong? ... Please help me out! Thank you for your answers.

Just to understand right, i wanna load the data from a "DLL" with another extension name, e.g '.src'.

Comment: I got it working! My bad, sorry

Comment: Just forgot to change the output extension